# Error in displaying hidden div tag

Tags: jquery, html, hidden

I have created a web application and in my index page there's a search button. when a user click on the search button i want to display a message by using JQuery fadeOut effect. but when I refresh or reload the index page that hidden div tag is displaying and after that it display the index page. How can i prevent this. Here is my code and could you please help me to solve this?

```
<!-- Starting unavelable page-->

<div  id="hidden_div" class="hidden_div">

    <div class="inner_div"><h2> These Services Will Be Coming Soon!</h2></div>
</div>
<!-- End-->


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

// when page loads #content_1 fades in over 4 seconds
$('#hidden_div').hide();

// Clicking show button fades in content_2 hides content_1
$('#search_botton').click(function(){
$('#hidden_div').fadeIn(1000);
});


$('#hidden_div').click(function(){
$('#hidden_div').fadeOut(1000);
});
// End Document ready
});
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have properly included jQuery....

Comment: Putting an exmaple in http://jsfiddle.net/ will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide it with inline css ;like

```
<div  id="hidden_div" class="hidden_div" style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

So the div is displaying during page load?

Did you try starting the div with css rule display:none, and removing it after the page is loaded, or on the first fade in?